# change color on recordset return using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, colors, conditional-statements

I am using a limited, known number of states for the status column in a MySQL table and would like to have an easily identifiable alert within to reflect a particular status.

How can you change the background color of a cell in a php generated HTML table according to the content of the 'status' column?

e.g. 'complete' = green, "pending' = orange

This is the entry for the table:

```
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['status']; ?> </td>
```

What php code can I add to the above to accomplish the conditional color change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this way can help....

**CSS**

```
.complete { background: green; }
.pending { background: orange; }
```

**php**

```
$status_class ="";
if($row_Recordset1['status'] == "complete"){
   $status_class = "complete";
}else if($row_Recordset1['status'] == "pending"){
   $status_class = "pending";   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td class='<?=$status_class;?>'><?php echo $row_Recordset1['status']; ?> </td>
```

Comment: @gungu thats great, don't forget to thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want...
But :

When you have your array of states, just do a foreach like :

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

  if($value['field'] == "car") {
   $color = red;
  }
  elseif($value['field'] == "bike") {
   $color = blue;
  }

}
```